# Convergence rate of $\operatorname E|\langle X,f_n\rangle|^p$

Tags: probability-theory, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal, rate-of-convergence

Suppose that $X$ is a random element with values in a separable Hilbert space $\mathbb H$ such that $\operatorname EX=0$ and $\operatorname E\|X\|^2<\infty$. Suppose that $f_1,f_2,\ldots$ form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb H$ (these might be eigenfunctions of the covariance operator of $X$). Then, by Parseval's identity, we have that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\operatorname E|\langle X,f_n\rangle|^2<\infty.
$$
In particular, $\operatorname E|\langle X,f_n\rangle|^2\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.

I am interested in $\operatorname E|\langle X,f_n\rangle|^p$ with $p>2$. If $\operatorname E\|X\|^{2(p-1)}<\infty$, using the fact that $\|f_j\|=1$ for $j\ge1$ and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality twice, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\operatorname E|\langle X,f_n\rangle|^p
&=\operatorname E[|\langle X,f_n\rangle||\langle X,f_n\rangle|^{p-1}]\\
&\le\operatorname E[|\langle X,f_n\rangle|\|X\|^{p-1}]\\
&\le(\operatorname E|\langle X,f_n\rangle|^2)^{1/2}(\operatorname E\|X\|^{2(p-1)})^{1/2}.
\end{align*}
This shows that $\operatorname E|\langle X,f_n\rangle|^p\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ as well, but at a slower rate than $\operatorname E|\langle X,f_n\rangle|^2$. The rate of convergence does not depend on $p$, which I find counterintuitive. Also, we need to assume that $\operatorname E\|X\|^{2(p-1)}<\infty$.

> At the moment, I have that $\operatorname E|\langle X,f_n\rangle|^p=O((\operatorname E|\langle X,f_n\rangle|^2)^{1/2})$ as $n\to\infty$. I suspect that $\operatorname E|\langle X,f_n\rangle|^p$ goes to $0$ faster than that. Is it possible to show that $\operatorname E|\langle X,f_n\rangle|^p\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ faster than $(\operatorname E|\langle X,f_n\rangle|^2)^{1/2}$?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: On the interval $[0, 1]$, one can't estimate $L^p$ norm $(p>2)$ in terms of $L^2$ norm, for reasons like $x^{-1/p}$... so it's not clear what kind of a bound you expect.

Comment: @SFTP Thanks for the comment. I updated my question to make it clearer.